# change value of file type

Tags: html

How can I change the value of `<input type='file'>` that the browsers displays by default?

Comment: Which value? The title of the button?

Comment: You can't, in the sense that it will only work in a few browsers. See alternatives in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Uploadify` for this

see this

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Answer (score 0):

The `value` attribute is not useful for `<input type='file'>`
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can't unless you use a javascipt library like [ajaxupload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) for example. This one allows you to use ANY HTML element as a file input, in fact it masks a file input element below the element you want, so you can give it the appearence you want and it will behave just like  the regular file input.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you can't!

But there are numerous JavaScript options that will allow you to fake it. Like using other elements for `<input type="file" />`.

See: http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/, http://valums.com/ajax-upload/, http://www.uploadify.com/ or just google for your "perfect" solution.